# Compound Interest

Tags: sequences-and-series

Samantha puts $1000 into a bank account at the beginning of each year, starting in 2010. At the end of each year 4% interest is added to the account.

Find an expression for the amount in the account at the beginning of year n.

My Approach:

After 1st Year,

$$1000(1.04) + 1000$$

After 2nd Year,

$$1000(1.04)^2 + 1000(1.04) + 1000$$

After 3rd Year,

$$1000(1.04)^3 + 1000(1.04)^2 + 1000(1.04) + 1000$$

And therefore,

$$U_n = (1000){\sum_{r = 0}^{n} 1.04^{r}}$$

However, the answer given in my textbook is:

$$U_n = 25000(1.04^n - 1)$$

Where did I go wrong? How can I get the textbook answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Both answers are the same.  Use G.P. summation to see that
$$\sum_{r=0}^r 1.04^k = \frac{1.04^{n}-1}{1.04-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Look up [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).